# How do I boot from an .hddimg file?

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake

After running BitBake on several different recipe files, BitBake generates a file of type '.hddimg'.  I haven't been able to find a clear explanation on what this file is used for, the closest that I have found is some speculation on the mailing list [here](https://lists.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2013-March/012815.html).  The author Paul states that:

> the image isn't an image of a regular bootable system drive, but is a "live
>   image" of a smaller system that can either boot the real system from a
>   virtualized file system in RAM whose image is read from a single file in the
>   first level, or it can install the real system to a different drive.

The 'bootimg.bbclass' is what generates the .hddimg, and in the opening comments it is written that:

> A .hddimg file [is] an msdos filesystem containing syslinux, a kernel, an initrd and a rootfs image. These can be written to harddisks directly and also booted on USB flash disks (write them there with dd).

Which appears to corroborate with what Paul wrote, but still leaves a lot of ambiguity on how to go about booting from this file (at least to a greenhorn like me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the doc says "write them there with dd". So:

```
dd if=/path/to/your/hddimg of=/path/to/raw/usb/device
```

so, if you have the file as my.hddimg and the usb flash disk appears as /dev/sdg

```
dd if=/home/karobar/my.hddimg of=/dev/sdg
```

As it's name implies, it's an *image*, so needs to be written as such. The actual file system is inside of the rootfs file, which is similarly an image!

Once you have that on the usb stick, the usb stick itself should be bootable. Depending on what you're trying to do this may not be the easiest kind of output from bitbake to work with.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response! I asked this question because I have already used dd to copy onto a flash drive, then copy from flash onto the hard disk of my target machine. Unfortunately, when booting that image on the hard disk, init-live.sh is executed and hangs on "Waiting for removable media...". I've looked at the commands in the file and it seems to hang because it can't find the root image within /run/media/.  I assumed that the root image was misplaced due to something in .hddimg. Was I wrong?

Comment: It's looking for the rootfs image on the usb stick. Consequently, when you moved it onto the hdd it could no longer find it. If you were to run it from hard disk with the usb stick plugged in, it would probably go to the usb stick and find the rootfs image. There's probably a yocto variable somewhere in the recipe tree that's defining where it's looking for the rootfs, I've not done much with the hddimage as I don't find it useful for my needs.